# Showing that the series $\sum \log{n}/n^2$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, convergence-divergence, logarithms

I aim to show that the series $$\sum \frac{\log{n}}{n^2}$$ converges.

I know that the inequality $log(n) < \sqrt{n}$ holds for large $n$. So this give us one way to prove the convergence of $\sum \log{n}/n^2$ (by comparison). But to obtain this inequality we have to define log rigorously and put more advanced stuff in the game. Can we demonstrate without using this kind of properties, without continuity, derivatives and integrals? You can use simple properties of log (of the sum or product), the limit $\log{n}/n\to 0$, etc.

Comment: To be clear, what explicit properties of log do you mean to permit?

Comment: How do you define log non-rigorously?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What kind of property do you allow for $\log$? Because if you don't want to "define it rigorously", you will have to throw some axioms for $\log$... otherwise how can you talk about something you know nothing about?

Comment: @Travis the relation between log and exp, log(ab)=log(a) + log(b), log(a/b)=log(a)-log(b), log(a^b)=b.log(a), log is strictly increasing, log1=0, log(n) tends to infty if n tends to infty, log(1/n) tends to -infty if n tends to infty.

Comment: if you want to impress your teacher, say that $\ln n = \mathcal{O}(n^{\epsilon})$ for every $\epsilon > 0$

Comment: @Hagen con Eitzen $log(a)$ is the number that we have to elevate $e$ to obtain $a$.

Comment: $-\zeta '(2)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\log (n)}{n^2}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can observe that, since $\log{n} \leq n $ for all $ n $,
$$\log{n} = \log{\sqrt{n}^2} = 2\log{\sqrt{n}} \leq 2\sqrt{n}$$

Asimptotically, the $ 2 $ changes nothing

Comment: ok, he still needs to know more stuff to see why that finishes the problem right?

Comment: Just that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^\alpha}$ converges, if $\alpha>1$.

Comment: exactly${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: If you want to see why that series converges you can just use the integral test.

Comment: But we can use numerical series stuff. This was good. Is there a simple way to prove that $\log{n} \leq n$?

Comment: Do you know how to show that exp(x) > x?

Comment: @Ryan for n large, yes. If $a>1$ and $p$ is a natural number fixed, $\lim a^n/n^p =\infty$. Put $a=e>1$ and $p=1$

Comment: @Jytug It is possible to show that $\log \sqrt{n} < \sqrt{n} assuming that $\log n < n$?

Comment: @FernandoVieiraCostaJúnior it's easier to do, assuming $ \log{x} \leq x $ for $ x $ real.

Comment: @Jytug yes, of course. But assuming only for $x\in\mathbb{N}$ I think that it is not possible.

Comment: @FernandoVieiraCostaJúnior it's possible to prove it without assuming anything

Comment: @Jytung nope. You will have to assume at least some axioms and others basic concepts.

Comment: Of course you will have to assume some basic concepts, what I mean is that proving the inequality $ \log \sqrt{n} \leq  \sqrt{n} $, knowing that $ \log n \leq n $ for integer $ n $ is not impossible

Answer (score 1):

You could use the integral test, since $\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln x \text{d}x}{x^2}=\int_0^\infty u\text{e}^{-u} \text{d}u=\left[\left(-1-u\right)\text{e}^{-u}\right]_0^\infty=1.$

Comment: I think this is the way to go, it also works if you want to prove the auxiliary result in the other solution.

Comment: But integrals is out of cogitation. We are in the fourth chapter of the book, and integrals content is in the chapter 10-11.

Comment: Mardon me, but a definition of log requires integral  or requires $\mathrm e^x$ be defined, which requires power series…

Comment: The trouble with a lot of these textbooks is that, because no-one really learned all of mathematics starting from axioms from which it can all be derived (unless you were taught set theory at school as part of the New Math), but rather learned things in a jumbled order, we feel like we "can use" logarithms before calculus. The best we can do to even define the original problem is to say $\log_b n := \lim_{k\to\infty}a_k$ for a sequence $(a_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $\lim_{k\to\infty}b^{a_k}=n$. So we have to verify the choice of $(a_k)$ is irrelevant...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Cantor criterion:

> Let $\{ a_n\}_n$ be a positive decreasing sequence of real numbers.
>
> $\sum_n a_n$ converges if and only if $\sum_n 2^n a_{2^n}$ converges.

Applying this criterion to your series, you need to show that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^n \frac{\log 2^n}{4^n}$$
converges. But now
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^n \frac{\log 2^n}{4^n} = \log 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{n}{2^n}$$
is convergent by the root test.

Comment: How can I prove that $\log n/n^2$ decreases?